# How to avoid writing "MySQLdb.connect" again and again?

Tags: python, mysql

I wonder if there is a way to avoid writing `MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='xyz', password='xyz', db='xyz')`
**again and again** in Python?

Example:

```
def Add_New_User(self):
    self.db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='xyz', password='xyz', db='xyz')
    self.cur = self.db.cursor()
```

after two or three lines (when new `def` is required and a lot of `def` is required), I need to write all over again the same string many times

```
def Add_New_User(self):
    self.db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='xyz', password='xyz', db='xyz')
    self.cur = self.db.cursor()
```

I hope that there is a way to call it in a simple way, like a connection code written and saved in, e.g., `MyConString.py` then in the new `def` say, `index.py`, I would simply call the function `MyConString`.

Comment: You already answered your own question. Create a function running these two lines and call it everywhere you need...

Answer (score 0):

Create a function called connection:

```
def conn(database):
    import mysql.connector
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database=database,
                                         user='root',
                                         password='yourpass')
    cursor = connection.cursor(buffered=True)
    return connection, cursor
```

Now, whenever you have to connect in any function do this:

```
def insert():
    connection_data = conn("mydatabase")
    connection = connection_data[0]
    cursor = connection_data[1]
    cursor.execute("show tables;")
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

You can even make an entirely new script for functions that are repeatedly used to keep your main file clean.
Then you can just add import connections.py(say, that is your file name which contains conn() function)

```
# This is your main.py
import connections
def insert():
    connection_data = connections.conn("mydatabase")
    connection = connection_data[0]
    cursor = connection_data[1]
    cursor.execute("show tables;")
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

Hope this helped!